# Does order of WHERE stmt params affect performance in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query in a sqlite database like so:

```
select from table where
   (a = 20 and b = 5 and c > 40) or
   (a = 20 and b > 5) or
   (a > 20) 
   order by a, b, c asc;
```

Will there be any performance difference if the order of the selection changes to this?:

```
select from table where
   (a > 20) or
   (a = 20 and b > 5) or
   (a = 20 and b = 5 and c > 40)
   order by a, b, c asc;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark this? That's probably the only way to find out. While the query-planner in SQLite seems to be pretty good (from what I've seen here and on its mailing-list), I suspect there will be some cases where the order of clauses can affect it.

Answer (score 0):

The [query planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) will always try to reorder terms. So how you write them in the query does not matter.